Symonfy Get->$user not valid
I'm trying to set up a new route in my Symfony application, but I'm getting a 404 error when I try to access it. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with my routing configuration?
here is my controller
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Story;
use App\Form\StoryType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

class MemberController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/member', name: 'app_member')]
    public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $stories = $entityManager->getRepository(Story::class)->findBy(['user' => $this->getUser()]);

        return $this->render('member/index.html.twig', [
            'stories' => $stories,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/member/insert', 'member_insert')]
    public function insertStory(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $message = 'Add story';

        $story = new Story();

        $form = $this->createForm(StoryType::class, $story);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $story->setUser($this->getUser());

            $entityManager->persist($story);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Successfully added a story');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_member');
        }

        return $this->render('adventure/handleStory.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
            'message' => $message
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/member/update/{id}', 'member_update')]
    public function updateStory(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, int $id)
    {
        $message = 'Update story';

        $story = $entityManager->getRepository(Story::class)->find($id);

        $form = $this->createForm(StoryType::class, $story);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager->persist($story);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Successfully updated a story');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_member');
        }

        return $this->render('adventure/handleStory.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
            'message' => $message,
        ]);
    }
}

this is my twig
<tbody>
                {% for story in stories %}
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{ story.title }}</th>
                        <td>{{ story.description }}</td>
                        <td>{{ story.date|date('d/m/Y') }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ path('member_update', { 'id' : story.id }) }}">
                                Update
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}

I double-checked the route path and the URL I am trying to access.
I cleared the Symfony cache using php bin/console cache:clear.
I verified that the HomeController file is in the correct namespace and directory.

#[Route('/admin/medewerkers', name: 'app_admin_employees')]
public function showEmployees(EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $request): Response
{
    $employees = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findBy(['roles' => array('["ROLE_DOCENT"]')]);

    return $this->render('admin/employees.html.twig', [
        'employees' => $employees,
    ]);
}

#[Route('/member/lessons', name: 'app_member_lessons')]
public function showLessons(EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
$user = $this->getUser();
$lessons = $em->getRepository(UserLesson::class)->findBy(['student' => $user]);
    return $this->render('member/lessons.html.twig', [
        'lessons' => $lessons,
    ]);
}

#[Route('/member', name: 'app_member')]
public function index(EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
$user = $this->getUser();
$stories = $em->getRepository(Story::class)->findBy(['user' => $user]);
    return $this->render('member/index.html.twig', [
        'stories' => $stories,
    ]);
}


$lessonAdd->setInstructor($this->getUser());


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
